# Fetch - API returns html instead of JSON - CORS error

Tags: cors, fetch-api

I have an assignment for a job opening to make a front-end app by fetching data from an external server. I am dealing with a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at (their URL) from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

This is my code:

```
 try {
const response = await fetch([their url], {
headers: {
Authorization: "Bearer xxxxxxxxxx",
Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
            "Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With, X-ACCESS_TOKEN, Accept",
        },
      });

const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
catch (error) {
console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I tried to put a proxy for the endpoint in `package.json`. I am no longer getting a CORS error but I am getting an HTML instead of JSON results.

The endpoint works fine in postman.

Comment: If you could bypass CORS by setting response headers on the client side, it would be completely pointless. A proxy only makes sense to simulate in a dev environment what would happen in the production environment - the _server_ needs to set those headers if you're really making cross-origin requests from the client.

Comment: Yeah it helps a lot to understand about cors. Thanks. But still I cannot make it work. Is it a backend issue?

Comment: @Effie: *"Is it a backend issue?"* - Maybe?  It depends on what functionality you're trying to achieve.  What is "their url" in the code shown?  Do you have any control over that service?  If that service allows cross-origin requests then you may need to check with them for the details on that.  If they don't allow cross-origin requests then the browser won't make those requests.  If that's the case then in order to get around it you'd need to proxy the request through a server that you *do* control.